# Attribute Routing Fail in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Why does the third route fail in my Web API ?

```
    public class StudentCourseController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/student
        public IEnumerable<StudentCourse> Get()
        {
            return StudentCourseRepository.GetAll();
        }

        // GET api/student/5
        public StudentCourse Get(int id)
        {
            return StudentCourseRepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
        }


        [Route("StudentAuto/{key}")]  // Does not work
        public IEnumerable<Student> StudentAuto(string key)
        {
            return StudentRepository.GetStudentsAuto(key);
        }
```

When i request `http://localhost:5198/api/StudentCourse/StudentAuto/mi` I get a 404 error.

The detail error shows

```
Requested URL      http://localhost:5198/api/StudentCourse/StudentAuto/mi
Physical Path      C:\Users\deb\Desktop\StudentKO\KnockoutMVC\KnockoutMVC\api\StudentCourse\StudentAuto\mi
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

Did i miss anything ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute routing on a method does not work in conjunction with the route constraints for the controller you put into your startup, e.g. `"/api/{controller}"`.

Therefore your `[Route("StudentAuto/{key}")]` route literally maps to `"/StudentAuto/{key}"`, not `"/api/StudentCourse/StudentAuto/{key}"`.

You can get this to work as you want by adding a `[RoutePrefix]` (see [msdn](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes)) to your controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/StudentCourse")]
public class StudentCourseController : ApiController
{
}
```

Alternatively just set the whole path in your `Route` attribute:

```
[Route("api/StudentCourse/StudentAuto/{key}")]
public IEnumerable<Student> StudentAuto(string key)
{
    return StudentRepository.GetStudentsAuto(key);
}
```

Comment: Any links / resources ? I cant add route prefix to the whole controller. My requirement is add RPC style actions where ever needed without breaking existing route structure.

Comment: By the way can you point me to any resources where it says Attribute Routing does not work with constraints ? I could not find any from the MSDN link you provided.